# Error when validating certificate

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl, x.509

I created a certificate signed by an intermediate CA that is signed by root CA following an online tutorial.

Reference to tutorial that I followed: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-certificate-chain-linux/

Please find the steps below:

```
openssl genrsa -out private/ca_key.pem 4096 ==> create private key for Root CA


openssl req -config openssl_root.cnf -key private/ca_key.pem -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -out certs/ca_cert.pem -subj "/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=ORG/OU=OU/CN=Root CA" ==> create CA certificate

openssl genrsa -out private/intermediate_key.pem ==> create private key for intermediate CA intermediate_key.pem


openssl req -config openssl_intermediate.cnf -key private/intermediate_key.pem -new -sha256 -out certs/intermediate_csr.pem -subj "/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=ORG/OU=OU/CN=Intermediate CA" ==> create csr certificate intermediate_csr.pem

openssl ca -config ../rootCA/openssl_root.cnf -extensions v3_intermediate_ca -days 3650 -notext -md sha256 -in certs/intermediate_csr.pem -out certs/intermediate_cert.pem ==> this will sign the certifitcate for the intermediate CA


cat certs/intermediate_cert.pem ../rootCA/certs/ca_cert.pem > certs/ca-chain_cert.pem ==> create certificate chain

openssl genrsa -out server_key.pem ==> create sever key server_key.pem

openssl req -config openssl_intermediate.cnf -key certs/server_key.pem -new -sha256 -out certs/server_csr.pem -subj "/C=FR/ST=Paris/L=Paris/O=ORG/OU=OU/CN=Server" ==> create csr for server


openssl x509 -req -in certs/server_csr.pem -CA certs/intermediate_cert.pem -CAkey private/intermediate_key.pem -out server_cert.pem -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha256 -extfile server_cert_ext.cnf ==> create a certificate for the server with SAN defined in the config file passed server_cert.pem
```

Now when I wanted to check the certificate, I ran the below command:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca_cert.pem -untrusted intermediate_cert.pem server_cert.pem ==> verify the certificarte
```

I get this output:

> C = FR, ST = Paris, O = ORG, OU = OU, CN = Intermediate CA error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid
> CA certificate error server_cert.pem: verification failed

Comment: When you generate the CA certificate, you read the configuration from `./openssl_root.cnf`. When you sign the intermediate certificate, you suddenly read the CA configuration from `../rootCA/openssl_root.cnf`. Are you sure you're not accidentally working with two different root CAs here? The commands generally look rather chaotic. Why does the server use the configuration of the *intermediate CA* when it generates its CSR? This makes no sense. In reality, the server wouldn't even have access to the internal configuration files of the CAs.

Comment: Hi @Ja1024, When I created the intermediate csr , I use the intermediate_openssl config file, which is normal since csr is created at the server that is asking for a certificate, and then this csr request is sent to the root CA, which will sign it an generate a certificate for the intermediate, so at this stage the root CA uses its own configuration file. isn't that the normal flow ? 
Did you check the reference I attached? it mentions my steps the same.

Comment: @Ja1024, if you look at the refence, search for "Sign the intermediate CSR with the root CA key:" below it you'll find the command used to sign the csr of the intermediate, and it uses the root config file.

Comment: What I'm saying is that when you provide the root CA configuration in the above commands, you use two different paths: `./openssl_root.cnf` and `../rootCA/openssl_root.cnf`. It's possible that it's actually the same file, and you've just omitted the information that you're switching directories between the commands. But that's something you should double-check. If you're accidentally using two different root CAs, that would explain the signature mismatch.

Comment: Hello @Ja1024, no they are the same file. Anws, I found the issue ! , the openssl_root.cnf file I copied it from the refence link I shared, but when copying them I missed the 2 lines below: 
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign